# Why path.resolve with string args print absolute path, but with variable args print relative path?

Tags: node.js, path, built-in

```
const path = require('path')

const file = path.join('/content', 'subfolder', 'first.txt')

const absoluteWithStrings = path.resolve(__dirname, 'content', 'subfolder', 'first.txt')
const absoluteWithVars = path.resolve(__dirname, file)

console.log(file)
console.log(absoluteWithStrings)
console.log(absoluteWithVars)
```

Why does `absoluteWithStrings` print the absolute path, BUT `absoluteWithVars` prints the relative path?

Screenshot shows output[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are absolute paths (they begin with `/`). The resolution algorithm goes right-to-left, not left-to-right, prepending each preceding path segment. In the second variable you're beginning the first string path segment with a slash, telling `resolve` that you want to start at `/`, effectively overriding the preceding `__dirname`.

Comment: Very interesting. When I removed the ```/``` from ```'/content'``` in ```file``` the ```absoluteWithVars``` now printed the absolute path. 
But I do not understand your point about the resolution algo going from right to left. How does that affect this?

Comment: They were both absolute paths, it's just that one doesn't actually exist on your filesystem. `/foo` is an absolute path, `foo` is not, and `./foo` is not. The right-to-left resolution affects this because path.resolve resolves an absolute path; once it hits a leading `/` in a segment, it stops building the path. [The relevant code is here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/path.js#L1095) — `resolvedAbsolute` tests if the resolved path so far begins with a `/`, and if so, goes on past the loop.